# PHP object invocation syntax

Tags: php

Given a piece of code such as:

```
{$globalScript->qtip(active_page::getCurrentPageName()=='factsheet','../')}
```

What's the difference in usage in PHP 5 between "->" and "::"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`->` calls the instance (object) method and `::` calls the class method, which is defined with the keyword `static`.

You can read more about that here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php and especially here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php.

Comment: you need the word static in there

Comment: Thanks, I added something about it.

Answer (score 2):

in `->` you are calling a public method in an object instance

and in `::` you are calling a static method

Ex:

```
Class MyClass {
    public function doStuff(){
        // stuff
    }

    public static function doStaticStuff (){
       // other stuff
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->doStuff(); // works


// in static you dont need to creat a new object
MyClass::doStaticStuff();

MyClass::doStuff(); // will fail here

// but you can also call the static method on an existing object
$obj::doStaticStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

`->` is used in object instance, where `::` is used in class methods.

Basically, the `::` is used for `static` methods and properties.